# Libraries that aid translating or converting file formats to other file formats

Tags: parsing, format, file-format, text-parsing

I need to convert genealogy files to and from the OpenGen XML file format.  Simple enough, I can write Java code to parse a particular file and output an OpenGen file.  If someone uses Java in their project, they can use our library.  If someone does not use Java in their project, they can either port our translating code or run our Java application externally.

Since this has to be a pretty common need, I'm hoping there's a mechanism out there to make this easier.  The ideal solution is this, I can create a file which contains rules/mappings to translate between one file format and our format.  This mapping file is then distributed so that anyone else can use one of many libraries that can perform the translation using this mapping file.  This way, translating is much easier and now anyone can do translations within their language/platform of choice.

I guess in our case, the mapping file would be a little complex in that there are at least hierarchies to deal with.  I guess further complicating things is that some genealogy file formats are binary...

Does such a mechanism exist?  What's the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

If your source language is always XML, you could use XSLT or [CDuce](http://www.cduce.org/).

Otherwise you'd need a decent parsing and pretty-printing framework, like Antlr, and be prepared to commit a lot of effort. For some trivial cases it's easier to implement your own combinator-based Packrat parser.

Comment: The source file format is rarely XML, as I mentioned in the question it is even binary for some file formats...  I'm checking out ANTLR, thanks.  At first glance it looks like a good tool to parse a file, given a grammar, but it's only Java and I still have to implement the translation process.

Comment: Antlr itself is in Java, but it targets a number of different platforms.